# Passing around an ElementTree

Tags: python, lxml

In my program, I need to make use of an ElementTree object in various functions in my program.

More specifically, I am doing this:

```
tree = etree.parse('somefile.xml')
```

I am passing this tree around in my program.

I was wondering whether this is a good approach, or can I do this:

1. Create a global tree (I come from a
   C++ background and I know global is
   bad)
2. Create the tree again wherever required.

Or is my approach ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, (eliding complexities, making an analogy for your C++ background) all objects are passed by reference. And since "tree" is an object, you're only passing the reference. Now, if you have a group of related methods that operate on the same tree, you might want to consider creating a class with that tree object as a member.

Also, here's a quick reference to the complexities I glossed over above: http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/5126

Answer (score 1):

Usually what I do is parse the tree using ElementTree and then convert the whole mess into a list of objects and pass that around instead - much easier to deal with afterwards as the rest of the code doesn't have to be aware that the stuff originated from some god-awful xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Passing it around is definitely better than recreating it every time you want to use it. Parsing the file is an expensive operation. [Here are some suggestions for performance improvements with lxml.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.dom.minidom as md
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def some_function():
    main_tag = ET.Element("main_tag")
    sub_tag = ET.SubElement(main_tag,"sub_tag")
    return(ET.tostring(main_tag))
def some_other_function():
    x = some_function()
    root = ET.fromstring(x)
    for tags in root:
        element_next = ET.SubElement(tags,"some_newtag")
dom = md.parseString(ET.tostring(root))
pretty_xml = dom.toprettyxml(indent="\t", encoding="utf-8")
print(pretty_xml)
```